# Syntax coloration on Monaco Editor (Monarch), '@popall' when new line encountered

Tags: syntax-highlighting, monaco-editor

I am currently writing a syntax highlighter for Monaco Editor, using [Monarch](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html).

I am using the `states` in order to deal differently with tokens depending on where they are in the line.

What I would like to do is **`@popall` the states when I reach the end of the line**, as all lines are independant.

Right now the only way I found is to add conditions at the end of all my rules, something like that:

```
[/\}/, {cases: {'@eos':{token: 'keyword', next:'@popall'},
                        '@default':{token: 'keyword', next:'@pop'}}}],
```

which is really redundant obviously as my 50+ rules have this case.

What is the clean way of doing this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on: " deal differently with tokens depending on where they are in the line". An example, perhaps. If you want to do semantics, try getting the abstract syntax tree with Babel(or JsCodeShift) and then play with Monaco decorations to change the coloring.